Adding the restrictions group field to the Users screen
Is it possible to add the "Group Name" field from the Restrictions Groups screen in the Row Level Security module to the Users screen (see images below)? The purpose of the change is to have the ability to add users to restriction groups directly from the Users screen. This would allow admins to control all access rights from one screen. Any information would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
Restrictions Groups screen
Users Screen
I'm assuming I'd have to link the data fields, but I'm having trouble getting it to work.
